# Titanium CloudPush properties on shared_prefs folder

Tags: android, properties, titanium, cloud

SDK 3.2.1, Android 4.2.2

Hi,
I've noticed CloudPush generates this file: `/data/data/your.app.id/shared_prefs/com.appcelerator.cloud.push.PushClient.xml`

with this content:

```
<map>
<string name="pushType">GCM</string><int name="pushUnreadNotifMsgCount" value="0"/><int name="GCMUsedAppVersion" value="1"/>
<long name="GCMOnServerExpirationTimeMs" value="0000000000000"/>
<string name="GCMRegistrationId">APA91bFg...mjhY</string>
<string name="GCMSenderId">219575370718</string>
<string name="appKey">A4pTGcJ1...vb7</string>
</map>
```

I've been caching CloudPush DeviceToken in Ti.App.properties!
**Can we retrieve this GCMRegistrationId from the above file?**
It's the CloudPush DeviceToken.

Answer (score 0):

Open this file with [`Titanium.Filesystem.getFile()`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Filesystem-method-getFile) and then parse it with [`Titanium.XML.parseString()`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.XML-method-parseString).

```
var filepath = Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory + 'shared_prefs/com.appcelerator.cloud.push.PushClient.xml';
var pushClientFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(filepath);
var pushClientXmlString = pushClientFile.read().toString();

var pushClientXml = Ti.XML.parseString(pushClientXmlString);

var node, registrationId;

for (var i = 0; i < pushClientXml.childNodes.length; i++) {
    node = pushClientXml.childNodes.item(i);
    if (node.getAttribute('name') === 'GCMRegistrationId') {
        registrationId = node.textContent;
        break;
    }
}

alert(registrationId);
```